# Amount Field Validation

Tags: validation

How to validate an amount field
with this requirements 
integer=34, fraction=4  and max_length=38.

I have tried the following code

```
public Boolean isrequestedLoanAmtValid() {

if (getRequestedLoanAmt() != null) {
                String amount = getRequestedLoanAmt().toString();
                System.out.println("length of amount"+amount.length());
                if (amount.contains(".")) {
                    if (amount.length() >= 38)
                          return false;
                } else {
                    if (amount.length() > 34) 
                          return false;
                }
            }
            return true;
        }
```

But it doesn't work.

Comment: why doesn't work? in which cases is it failing?

Comment: This looks like Java. Please add some applicable tags to your question to get the proper attention (e.g. the `java` tag ).